# Proving that $b=(e_1,...,en_,f(e_1),...,f(e_n),f^2(e_1),...,f^2(e_n))$ is base of $E$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose that $E=S\oplus \ker{f^2}$, and $f$ an endomorphism, $S$ is the
>   base of $(e_1,...,e_n)$ and $f^3=0_{L(E)}$.
>
> How can I prove that
>   $b=(e_1,...,e_n,f(e_1),...,f(e_n),f^2(e_1),...,f^2(e_n))$ is base of
>   $E$?

**I'm certain that $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is base of $S$, so I just need to prove that $(f(e_1),...,f(e_n),f^2(e_1),...,f^2(e_n))$ is base of $\ker{f^2}$.**

Comment: You have to show that that set is linearly independent and that it spans ker $f^2$; as usual, attack those two parts separately. The fact that $E$ is a direct sum is crucial (it should help you show that $\{f(e_i)\}$ is linearly independent, for starters). Maybe try to show that ker $f^2$ is itself the direct sum of ker $f$ and a complementary piece?

Comment: You're quite right, but now I just need to prove the independence of $(f^2(e_1),...,f^2(e_n))$.

Comment: Try the same trick again: just like $S$ being a direct sum helped you prove that $\{f(e_i)\}$ is linearly independent, use the fact that you've decomposed ker$(f^2)$ into a direct sum to prove that $\{f^2(e_i)\}$ is linearly independent.